# Elementor Blocks For Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

I was using Elementor Blocks For Gutenberg for last 1 month but not facing any issue but know when I am performing the same technique now I am facing the issue that is, When I am selecting Elementor Library Block to integrate a template on the page, I am receiving an error message "This block has encountered an error and can not be previewed." When I inspect it on Google/Bing I get this code which defines my error.

```
TypeError: t.replace is not a function
    at a11y.min.js?ver=7032343a947cfccf5608:2:2078
    at p (a11y.min.js?ver=7032343a947cfccf5608:2:2125)
    at components.min.js?ver=f6e63a4760dcece8b909:48:548568
    at Ur (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73411)
    at El (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:93232)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:91974
    at xl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:92039)
    at fl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85808)
    at Nn (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:32474)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:83226
ar @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
```

I don't know what to do.

I checked if there is any conflict with the other plugin. There is no conflict.
I cleared the cache of the website. I also cleared the cache of Elementor but nothing worked.